# How to get decimal in simple addition in c#?

Tags: c#, types, double, decimal

there is a `double d = 4.0` and i take another `double` value from user and add them then the value should come till 1 decimal place.
Ex. `double d = 4.0`
and user enters `1` then the answer should be `5.0` not just `5`.

Comment: You need to differentiate between the number itself and a formatted value. You also need to work out whether you *actually* want to use `double` or `decimal`, which are two different types (with different behaviour). I suspect you probably want to use `decimal`, but it's unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
double d1 = 4.0;
double d2 = 1;

var result = d1 + d2;

// Will result in System.Double
result.GetType();

// Will result in 5
result.ToString();

// Will result in £5.00 in the UK (different in different countries, because this is culture specific)
result.ToString("C");

// Will result in 5.000 in the UK, but can also be 5,000 in other countries due to a different culture.
result.ToString("N3");
```

Same applies for `decimal`. If accuracy is important like with currencies, then you should use `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

try  (substitute your variable name in place of decimalVariable

```
    decimalVariable.ToString ("#.#");
```